# Fetching generated file from webpage

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm currently creating a method that extracts information from a webpage.
The webpage is the following:

http://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/annceresult/annceresult_query.htm

My problem is that I don't want to extract the information directly from the page, instead I want to use the given there to generate a file with the information, the auto generated file is a CSV or XML and haves all the information i need, so i'm planning on doing the extracting over that document.

So, finnally, I'm looking for a way to get into the link I gave before; generate and download the document with the information; and import it into php to extract information.

I'm trying to achive this using PHP over Zend framework.

PD: sorry for any dificulties on the explanation, English isn't my main languaje (actually I speak spanish).

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? The `Zend_Http_Client` class will make the request for you, this article explains how to make a `POST` request with it: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2011/04/13/post-with-zend_http_client/

Comment: I haven't tried much, i'm new at PHP and ZEND, soy I'm having dificulties even in knowing where to start looking.
Know i'm trying using a curl approach, but I don't really know where this attempt will be heading to or where to start! I'll take a look to the webpage you gave me! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you some general pointers about how to accomplish your goal. Here is my example scenario (this is just a made-up example, the supplied code will not do anything):

**Target Site:** http://www.example.com

**Target form:**

```
<form action="/getresults.php" method="POST">
    Search term: <input type="text" name="query" value="" />
    Output type:
    <select name="output_format">
        <option value="CSV">CSV</option>
        <option value="JSON">JSON</option>
        <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

1. Inspect the form parameters, method, and action url of your target. This will provide you with the parameters that you need to pass, the method (`GET`, `POST`, etc.) and the URL that you need to make your request to. In my example, we have two parameters (`output_format` and `query`), an endpoint url (`http://www.example.com/getresults.php`) and a request type (`POST`)
2. Setup your Zend_Http_Client

   ```
   $client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://www.example.com/getresults.php');
   // set your parameters
   $client->setParameterPost('output_format', 'CSV');
   $client->setParameterPost('query', 'My fancy search term');
   // POST request
   $response = $client->request(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
   ```
3. Save the response body to a file:

   ```
   file_put_contents('path/to/output/file.csv', $response->getBody());
   ```
4. In (presumably) a separate controller/action, get the contents of the file and iterate over it using `fgetcsv`:

   ```
   $rows = array()
   if (($handle = fopen("path/to/output/file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
       while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
           array_push($rows, $data);
       }
       fclose($handle);
   }
   print_r($data);die;
   ```

I hope this helps you understand the process better and you are able to put the pieces together.

Comment: THANKS! I got help from a coworker to find the http request, and then did as you sayed, thanks again!